# Receive timed out in Java UDP socket client for Memcached

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, memcached

I have a local Memcached instance and trying to access it by basic Java TCP and UDP socket API. TCP client is working fine but UDP client always throwing below exception.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:144)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812)
    at test.Test.udp(Test.java:71)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

No matter what timeout I am setting.

Here is the code I am running. I am new to socket programming Please help to figure out the problem.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        //tcp();
        udp();
    }

    private static void tcp(){
        String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 11211;
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
            Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);

            System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            out.writeBytes("stats\r\n");
            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

            System.out.println("Server says " + in.readLine());

            client.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void udp(){
        DatagramSocket socket = null ;

        try
        {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost") ;
            socket = new DatagramSocket() ;
            byte [] data = "stats\r\n".getBytes() ;
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, host, 11211 ) ;
            socket.send( packet ) ;
            socket.setSoTimeout( 2000 ) ;
            packet.setData( new byte[1024] ) ;
            socket.receive( packet ) ;
            System.out.println( new String(packet.getData()) ) ;

        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println( e ) ;
        }
        finally
        {
            if( socket != null )
                socket.close() ;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could try catching the Timeout exception and loop around to try and receive again.

Comment: @SteveSmith I tried with 100 times retry in a loop Still got no luck.

Comment: Is the server actually sending a response?

Comment: I used the below command to check if the server is listening for UDP. sbm@LISP:~$nc -v -u -z -w 3 127.0.0.1 11211-11211
Connection to 127.0.0.1 11211 port [udp/*] succeeded!                      Please let me to If there is better way to check if server actually sending a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to memcached documentation (https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) , while sending data using udp protocol, 8 byte header should be sent  followed by data in the
same format as the TCP protocol. The header structure is as follows :

- 0-1 Request ID
- 2-3 Sequence number
- 4-5 Total number of datagrams in this message
- 6-7 Reserved for future use; must be 0

Add header bytes while sending data. Something like this:

```
    try
    {
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost") ;
        socket = new DatagramSocket() ;

        byte [] data = "stats\r\n".getBytes() ;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(50);
        buffer.putShort((short)0);
        buffer.putShort((short) 0x0000;);
        buffer.putShort((short) 0x0001;);
        buffer.putShort((short) 0x0000;);
        buffer.put(data);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buffer.array(), buffer.array().length, host, 11211 ) ;
        socket.send( packet) ;
        socket.setSoTimeout( 2000 ) ;
        packet.setData( new byte[1024] ) ;
        socket.receive( packet ) ;
        System.out.println( new String(packet.getData()) ) ;

    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if( socket != null )
            socket.close() ;
    }
```